# How do you communicate between Rake tasks?

Tags: ruby, rake

Let's say I have a target who needs to compile some files. That target has another target as a prerequisite, one that obtains the files.
Let's say this:

```
task :obtain do
  # obtain files from somewhere
end

task :compile => :obtain do
  # do compilation
end
```

Let's say that the `:obtain` target doesn't always places the files in the same folder. How would I pass `:compile` the path that `:obtain` found? Environment variables?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Using ENV['something'] is in my opinion preferable, because if you do it this way (as opposed to $global or @instance variables) you can treat those as task arguments, and use the sub task from commandline easily.

On the other hand if you keep your code in separate classes / modules / methods, you will not even have to deal with those sorts of hacks + your code will be more testable.

Comment: Yeah. This is how I ended up doing it. Thanks!

Comment: It should be borne in mind that ENV can only take strings as keys and values, so while this restriction may not matter in the case of filenames, it may not be a good solution when dealing with other kinds of values.

Answer (score 11):

One way would be to store it in a global variable:

```
task :obtain do
  $obtained_dir = "/tmp/obtained"
end

task :compile => :obtain do
  puts "compiling files in #{$obtained_dir}"
end
```

Instance variables (i.e. `@obtained_dir`) should also work.

Another way would be to pull the "obtain" code into a method, as follows:

```
task :obtain do
  obtain_files
end

task :compile do
  obtained_dir = obtain_files
  puts "compiling files in #{obtained_dir}"
end

def obtain_files
  #obtain files from somewhere
  "/tmp/obtained_files"
end
```

Comment: +1 for the put-it-in-a-method way to do this.  task :obtain doesn't seem like it's a task at all, it's just a method that other people call.