# Capistrano how to access a serverDefinition option in the code

Tags: capistrano

I am defining my server setup like this:

```
task :test do
  role(:frontend) {[server1,server2,server3, {:user=> "frontend-user", :options => {:log_location=>"HOW DO I READ THIS??"}}]}
  role(:backend) {...}
  role(:db) {...}
  role(:mq) {...}
end

task :staging do
  role(:frontend) {[server1,server2,server3, {:user=> "frontend-user", :options => {:log_location=>"HOW DO I READ THIS??"}}]}
  role(:backend) {...}
  role(:db) {...}
  role(:mq) {...}
end

task :prod do
  role(:frontend) {[server1,server2,server3, {:user=> "frontend-user", :options => {:log_location=>"HOW DO I READ THIS??"}}]}
  role(:backend) {...}
  role(:db) {...}
  role(:mq) {...}
end
```

This is to embrace all the complexity of a legacy enterpricey system.

Now, from a task, I want to read the `log_location`.

Task example:

```
namespace :log do
  desc "list all log files"
  task :list do
    run %(ls -1 #{log_location}/*/*.log)
  end
end
```

The problem is that the variable `log_location` is undefined.

> /.rvm/gems/ruby-2.0.0-p0/gems/capistrano-2.14.2/lib/capistrano/configuration/namespaces.rb:193:in
>   `method_missing': undefined local variable or method`log_location'
>   for
>   # (NameError)

1. How do I access that variable?
2. Is there a smarter/simpler way of setting this custom variable?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339987/how-do-you-communicate-between-rake-tasks can perhaps be helpful? Or is that too crude?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry to say you can't read that. The blocks passed to `task()` aren't executed in a server context, thus the block in effect doesn't know what server it's operating on.

The classical workaround for this over the years has been to upload a config file which looks something like this:

```
---
  hostname1:
    log_file_location: "/var/log/hostname1/foo/bar"
  hostname2:
    log_file_location: "/var/log/hostname2/foo/bar"
```

(or similar) and use the machines hostname when loading the configuration.

I know this isn't a great workaround, thus in the forthcoming (see the v3 branch at Github) version of Capistrano there's a feature which looks like this:

```
host1 = SSHKit::Host.new 'user@example.com'
host2 = SSHKit::Host.new 'user@example.org'

host1.properties = {log_file_location: "/foo/bar"}
host2.properties.log_file_location = "/bar/baz"

on hosts do |host|
  target = "/var/www/sites/"
  if host.hostname =~ /org/
    target += "dotorg"
  else
    target += "dotcom"
  end
  execute! :head, '-n 20', host.properties.log_file_location
  execute! :git, :clone, "git@git.#{host.hostname}", target
end
```

([SSHKit Examples](https://github.com/leehambley/sshkit/blob/master/EXAMPLES.md#do-something-different-on-one-host-or-another-depending-on-a-host-property)) - `SSHKit` is the new backend driver for Capistrano.

The v3 branch probably isn't ready for prime time yet, we're having a lot of success internally but the documentation is pretty *ahem* non existent. However the code is quite literally an oder of magnitude less imposing, and I think you'll find quite readable.

Answer (score 0):

You need this: https://github.com/capistrano/capistrano/wiki/2.x-Multistage-Extension

It means that you can isolate stage specific code in separate files named after the stage. If you want to test for the stage name in the shared deploy.rb you can do that too, like this:

Put this in your deploy.rb

```
task :show_stage do
   puts(stage)
end
```

Test from command line

```
$ cap staging show_stage
staging
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I was able to pull out the `log_location` variable, but ended up with a solution that had one restriction:

I am using log location for one environment only. This is no problem in my current project, since I run the capistrano task against one role at a time.

For testing this setup, I made this task:

```
namespace :support do 
  desc "Test if the log location variable is correctly fetched from configuration"
  task :test_log_location do
    find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
      # puts server.host
      # puts server.port
      # puts server.user
      # puts server.options
      result = "LOG LOCATION: #{server.options[:log_location]}"
      #puts result
      logger.info result 
    end
  end
end
```

Then, for my tasks in the :log namespace, I defined the variable with `set :log_location` and also define the `:current_role` variable:

```
namespace :log do
  def set_log_location 
    #set_log_location
    #puts fetch(:log_location)
    log_location = nil
    options      = nil
    find_servers_for_task(current_task).each do |server|
      # puts server.host
      # puts server.port
      # puts server.user
      # puts server.options
      options = server.options
      log_location = server.options[:log_location]
      #log_location = server.options[:current_role]
    end
    msg1="FATAL: you need to specify 'ROLES=frontend,backend,mq' (or one of them) from command line"
    msg2="FATAL: Could not get log_location from environment/server options. I can only see these options: #{options}"

    raise msg1 if ENV['ROLES'].nil? 
    raise msg2 if log_location.nil?

    set :log_location, log_location
    set :current_role, ENV['ROLES'].split(',').first
    logger.info %(CURRENT_ROLE #{fetch(:current_role)})
    logger.info %(THE LOG LOCATION IS: #{fetch(:log_location)})
  end
end
```

Finally, I used a separate method to fully qualify the log path (needed for my setup -- also in the `:log` namespace):

```
  def log_location
    log_names = {
      :frontend => "*/play.log",
      :backend => "*Weblogic*/*.{log,out}"
    }
    loc = "#{fetch(:log_location)}/#{log_names[fetch(:current_role).to_sym]}"
    logger.info "using the log location of '#{loc}'"
    loc
  end
```

Now, each task can use the specific log location like this:

```
  desc "list all log files"
  task :list do
    set_log_location
    run %(ls -l #{log_location})
  end
```

I am sure this can be done more elegant, but it works for me